# laravelのバリデーションにてエラーが発生

Tags: php, laravel

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 実現したいこと

画像を投稿できる機能を実装しているのですが、
そのフォームに対して添付写真のエラーが出てしまいます。

### 発生している問題

画像なしでの投稿時にエラーが発生。
getClientOriginalName()on nul

### 試したこと

getClientOriginalName()on nulがエラーの原因のため、
一度削除してみたがその場合、テーブルにランダムな文字列で画像が保存されてしまうようになった。
getClientOriginalNameがnullでも通る方法を検索したが、解決できず。

足りないファイル等ございましたら、ご指摘いただけると幸いです。
ご教授宜しくお願いいたします

Comment: getClientOriginalNameがnullなのではなくてその前のimageがnullだから、nullにgetClientOriginalNameメソッドなんかないよというエラーです

Comment: ありがとうございます！getClientOriginalNameではなくメソッドのかかり元が原因だったのですね！実装できました！ありがとうございます！